# using jquery, remove all the table elements except the last one

Tags: jquery, html

In my HTML page, I have a table with the id ="productsTable", I wanna remove all its elements except the last one.

I started by this code which will remove all the elements:

```
$('#productsTable').empty();
```

Comment: what is the last element you wanna keep ?

Comment: a small html example would be helpful here

Comment: the last element is a <tr> <td id="product">

Comment: do you mean the all rows except the last

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know the last HTML element but something like this?

```
$("#productsTable:not(:last-child)").empty();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("#productsTable").find("tr:not(:last)").remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vW5W/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use:

$`("#productsTable tr").not(":last").remove()`

[Little example](http://jsfiddle.net/6nm85/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$('#productsTable tr').slice(0, -1).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VPRg8/)